# how do i seek and take snapshots from time stamps stored in an array in secounds / NO jQuery

Tags: javascript, for-loop, html5-canvas, html5-video, snapshot

i have predefined times stored in an array. i wrote a for loop to go threw an array and take snapshots from canvas and append them to a div  via onclick event. The problem is that i can only get the last snapshot unless i put an alert between snapshots. I tried using a seeked listener ,setting a timeout and I tried putting the snapshot function in a while loop waiting on a variable to change but i can only get the last timestamp in the array to take a snapshot unless there is an alert or confirm in the loop.

[Codepin Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gaMbxp)

HTML

```
    <div id="DesiredvideoPlayer" >

    <br>

<video muted controls  id="videoPlayer" style="float: left;">

        <source id='currentVID' src="http://html5multimedia.com/code/ch9/media/elephants-dream-medium.mp4" >
</video>
<br>
    <div id="PreCHPscroll">Array snaps
    </div>

    <div id="snapshotscroll">Manual Snaps
    </div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" id="Alerts">: alert between snapshots</div>
    </div>
<button id="snap" onclick="PreCHps()">Snapshots from array</button>
<button id="snap" onclick="snap()">Take Snapshot</button>
```

CSS

```
video, canvas {
    /border:1px solid #000;
}
#DesiredvideoPlayer{
    background-color:grey;
    /width: 100%;
    /height:auto;
    /height:100%;
    /display: block;;
    /display: inline-block;
}
#PreCHPscroll {
    outline: 1px solid steelblue;
    width: auto;
    height:120px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    /font-size: 0px;
}
#snapshotscroll {
    outline: 1px solid steelblue;
    width: auto;
    height:120px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.snapshots {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

JAVACRIPT

```
var CHPcategory_ALL_ = [5,63,264,348,479,512,551,600];
function PreCHps() {
    scrollDIV = 'PreCHPscroll';

    if(document.getElementById("videoPlayer").readyState >= 4) {
        document.getElementById("videoPlayer").addEventListener("seeked", ready2snap );

    for (i = 0; i < CHPcategory_ALL_.length; i++) {
//!!!!!!! toggle alert  
    if (document.getElementById("Alerts").checked == true){
    alert("snapshot#" + snapcount);
    }
//!!!!!!! toggle alert  
       setTimeout(next(), 1500);
    }
        setTimeout(chpThumbsMade, 1500);

    }
}
function next(){ document.getElementById("videoPlayer").currentTime= CHPcategory_ALL_[i];
}
function chpThumbsMade(){
    scrollDIV = 'snapshotscroll';
document.getElementById("videoPlayer").removeEventListener("seeked", ready2snap );
}
function ready2snap(){
    scrollDIV = 'PreCHPscroll';
    snap();

}
/********* snap shot script ********/
var w = 200, h = 100, snapcount = 0, scrollDIV = 'snapshotscroll';
function snap() {

    snapcount = snapcount+1;
        var snapnum = "snapshot#" + snapcount;
    //alert(snapnum);
    // make new div
    var newsnap = document.createElement('div');
    newsnap.id =  (snapnum);
    newsnap.className = 'snapshots';
    //var scrollDIV = scrollDIV ;
    document.getElementById(scrollDIV).appendChild(newsnap);


    var crrntTsec = document.getElementById('videoPlayer').currentTime;
    var clckFnct = 'document.getElementById("videoPlayer").currentTime=' + crrntTsec;

    document.getElementById(snapnum).setAttribute('onclick', clckFnct);

    var cv = document.createElement("canvas");
    cv.width = w;
    cv.height = h;


        // Get timestamp
    var Tsec = Math.floor(document.getElementById('videoPlayer').currentTime);


        // convert to time stamp
    var hour = Math.floor(Tsec / 3600);
    var min = Math.floor(Tsec / 60);
    var secs = (Tsec - (min * 60));

    hour = (hour >= 10) ? hour : "0" + hour;
    min = (min >= 10) ? min : "0" + min;
    secs = (secs >= 10) ? secs : "0" + secs;
    var Tstamp = hour+ ":" +min+ ":" +secs ;


    document.getElementById(snapnum).appendChild(cv);
    var cx = cv.getContext('2d');
    cx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h); 

    // Grab the image from the video
    cx.drawImage(document.getElementById('videoPlayer'), 0, 0, w, h);
         cx.font = "12pt Calibri";


        cx.strokeStyle="#40FF00";
        cx.strokeText(Tstamp, 5, 95);
        cx.strokeText(Tstamp, 6, 96);
        cx.strokeText(Tstamp, 6, 97);
        cx.strokeText(Tstamp, 7, 95);
   cx.fillStyle = "#000000";
   cx.fillText(Tstamp, 6, 96);


    document.getElementById(scrollDIV).scrollLeft +=  5000;

}
```

[Codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gaMbxp)

Comment: `setTimeout(next(), 1500)` should probably be `setTimeout(next, 1500)`.

Comment: RobG  for some reason i don't get any snapshots from that button when i remove "()" from "setTimeout(next(), 1500)"

Comment: I'm making some progress with it. It looks like your strategy is to have the video go to each timestamp in the array, get a snapshot of the frame, and then insert it into the PreCHPscroll div? And I'm guessing you intend to reduce the setTimeout delay as much as possible? Also, the reason he made that suggestion is that your `setTimeout(next(), 1500)` was calling `next` immediately because you put the parentheses in there.

Comment: Jason  your right but when i remove the parentheses the fiction doens't get called at all i put an alert in it to see if it was called and i never get the alert or anything at all

Comment: get rid of the `for` loop. you have a classic case of a loop without a closure and `i` isn't what you want it to be when it gets used

Comment: charlietfl   if i dont use a "for loop" how would i go about going threw the array ? The array length may change depending on what video is being used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not ideal, but it works. Here's your JavaScript:

```
var CHPcategory_ALL_ = [5, 63, 264, 348, 479, 512, 551, 600];

var CHPindex = 0;

function PreCHps() {
  scrollDIV = 'PreCHPscroll';
  if (document.getElementById("videoPlayer").readyState >= 4) {
    document.getElementById("videoPlayer").addEventListener("seeked", ready2snap);
    console.log(CHPindex);
    document.getElementById("videoPlayer").currentTime = CHPcategory_ALL_[CHPindex];
  }
}

function ready2snap() {
    snap();
    document.getElementById("videoPlayer").removeEventListener("seeked", ready2snap);

    if (CHPindex < CHPcategory_ALL_.length - 1) {
      CHPindex++;
      PreCHps();
    } else {
      CHPindex = 0;
      scrollDIV = 'snapshotscroll';
    }

  }

  /********* snap shot script ********/
var w = 200,
  h = 100,
  snapcount = 0,
  scrollDIV = 'snapshotscroll';

function snap() {

  snapcount = snapcount + 1;
  var snapnum = "snapshot#" + snapcount;
  //alert(snapnum);
  // make new div
  var newsnap = document.createElement('div');
  newsnap.id = (snapnum);
  newsnap.className = 'snapshots';
  //var scrollDIV = scrollDIV ;
  document.getElementById(scrollDIV).appendChild(newsnap);

  var crrntTsec = document.getElementById('videoPlayer').currentTime;
  var clckFnct = 'document.getElementById("videoPlayer").currentTime=' + crrntTsec;

  document.getElementById(snapnum).setAttribute('onclick', clckFnct);

  var cv = document.createElement("canvas");
  cv.width = w;
  cv.height = h;

  // Get timestamp
  var Tsec = Math.floor(document.getElementById('videoPlayer').currentTime);

  // convert to time stamp
  var hour = Math.floor(Tsec / 3600);
  var min = Math.floor(Tsec / 60);
  var secs = (Tsec - (min * 60));

  hour = (hour >= 10) ? hour : "0" + hour;
  min = (min >= 10) ? min : "0" + min;
  secs = (secs >= 10) ? secs : "0" + secs;
  var Tstamp = hour + ":" + min + ":" + secs;

  document.getElementById(snapnum).appendChild(cv);
  var cx = cv.getContext('2d');
  cx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);

  // Grab the image from the video
  cx.drawImage(document.getElementById('videoPlayer'), 0, 0, w, h);
  cx.font = "12pt Calibri";

  cx.strokeStyle = "#40FF00";
  cx.strokeText(Tstamp, 5, 95);
  cx.strokeText(Tstamp, 6, 96);
  cx.strokeText(Tstamp, 6, 97);
  cx.strokeText(Tstamp, 7, 95);
  cx.fillStyle = "#000000";
  cx.fillText(Tstamp, 6, 96);

  document.getElementById(scrollDIV).scrollLeft += 5000;

}
```

Comment: THANKS JASON !!!! very clever i had that idea but i didn't know how to go about writing it. i'm wondering why you said its not ideal? i guess i'll find out while i rewriting it into my project...THANKS

Comment: I don't like CHPindex as a global variable. I could have written a more elegant solution if I took more time with it, maybe with recursion. The event listener callback really complicates things, though.